# Making Ajax Post request -> vb 7.1

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, server

I've seen a lot of online help and nothing is working. This is my first time with vb.net

I have a file called

```
AddRecord.aspx
```

In the same folder I have a file called

```
AddRecord.aspx.vb
```

In AddRecord.aspx I have

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           url: "AddRecord.aspx/getCurrentTime",
           data: '{something:"hello"}',
           dataType: "json",
           success: function (result) {
                alert("success");
           },
           error: function (result) {
                alert("Error");
           }
       });
});
```

And in AddRecord.aspx.vb I have this

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Script.Services
Imports System.Net.Mail
Imports System.DirectoryServices
Imports System.Web.Security

Imports Web.SmartNav

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Sub getCurrentTime(ByVal name As String)

        Return

    End Sub
```

Running AddRecord keeps giving me the alert error and not the success alert, so what am I doing wrong? And how can I tell if my function is being called (this is my first time on visual basic and visual studio)?

Comment: I haven't seen any cases in the past of someone writing a Web API service into the codebehind of an ASP.NET Web Form.  From what you've written I'm not sure that you would get a response from the service without a postback, which would be completely not what you want.  Is there a particular reason you've put the web API in the codebehind page of the client?

Comment: @manlak1982 no particular reason to put it there. so what should I do if I want to send a post request to code in vb?

Comment: I would make separate projects in the same solution for the front-end code (ASPX if you like, though it's not the only choice and you can even just write a regular HTML page) and for the server-side code (Web Method, from what I can tell).  Web forms is an older paradigm that is meant to mimic the behavior of Windows forms by posting back to the same page and having server code execute based on client-side events.  I have the impression you want to just execute client-side code that calls a RESTful service, which doesn't require WebForms at all.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "VB 7.1"? Are you using .NET 1.1?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the WebApi defined in the codebehind of the client Web Form.  A Web Form uses a postback model to run Server-side code that is linked to client-side controls via event handlers, which I don't think is necessary in this case.  I don't know that the Postback model would interfere with the WebApi, but I would avoid it to make it easier to debug this problem.

I'm not sure exactly what you are wanting to do with your web service, as you are posting to a method that by naming convention seems to be intended for a GET.  It might be helpful for you to start from a tutorial.  Microsoft provides one on this page, though it is in C#:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api